# Cannot use nosort for cleveref

Tags: cleveref, sorting

I found sorting and compressing not very intelligent for cleveref package when the labels are in different sections, so I decide to disable sorting and compressing. However I am unable to use nosort for cleveref.

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[nosort]{cleveref}
\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[subsection]
\crefname{Thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\begin{document}
\begin{Thm}\label{T1}
This is Theorem 1.
\end{Thm}
\cref{T1}
\end{document}
```

When compiling, the log file looks like the following.

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>
> \cref@processgroup ...ref \cref@isrefsametypetrue 
>                                                     \@whilesw \if@cref@sametyp...
>
> l.8 \cref{T1}
>                 ?
>
> Process has been terminated ...

What change should I make?

Comment: I think this has already been reported. Have you tried updating your latex installation (IIRC there was a problem in `etoolbox` what is now fixed)

Comment: A similar problem has been reported a few days back. The `cleveref` developer is looking into it and has already posted a pre-release version for testing on his webage: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414211/35864

Comment: Please note that TeX.SX is not a place to report bugs. In particular, Toby Cubitt, the cleveref developer, is very clear about the fact that he cannot guarantee he sees all questions posted here on TeX.SX. But he will definitely read his mails. So if you want to report a bug, send it off via the channels mentioned in the package documentation.